# Define a limit on which a stripe subscription invoice is effective or not

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I've been using Stripe to start subscriptions for my clients recently and I have a specific issue.

I have a metered price for a product that's let's say 0.09€ per item (an SMS in that case) on a monthly cycle. Since you pay on Stripe for your invoices, I'd like to define an amount limit to have this invoice sent or not. For example, let's say this amount is 10€ and the the pending invoice amount at the end of the month for a user is 5€, I'd like to carry these 5€ over the next month.

I read about the `billing_thresholds.amount_gte` which does basically the opposite of what I need from what I understand.

Is this possible?